# How to change the color of text assigned to a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code to assign text to a variable. I'd like to change the color of the text.

```vb
If Sheet1.Range("N17") = 2 Then
    request = " Quote"
Else
    request = " Purchase"
End If
```

The spreadsheet is then saved as a pdf, and an email is sent. I want the body of the email to display the 'request variable' in a color based on whether it is a `'purchase'` or `'quote'`.

```vb
.Body = "Please find attached a requisition to" & request & " material for the above mentioned job." & vbNewLine & _
        "If you have any questions please let me know." & vbNewLine & _
        "Thank You" & vbNewLine & _
```

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of a variable? Do you need, in fact, to color a string in the email body? If yes, please show us what did you try by your own.

Comment: Make the email an HTML email and write HTML into your `.Body`. You can find tons of information how to color words in HTML on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.HTMLBody`

```vb
    If Sheet1.Range("N17") = 2 Then
        request = "<span style=""color:red"">Quote</span>"
    Else
        request = "<span style=""color:blue"">Purchase</span>"
    End If

     .HTMLBody = "<p>Please find attached a requisition to " & request & _
        " material for the above mentioned job.</p>" & _
        "<p>If you have any questions please let me know.</p><p>Thank You</p>"
```